# Difficult SOQL query for Id between dates

Tags: soql, query, date

Can anyone help me?
Can I realize in soql query next fetch:

I have a `map Map< Id, List< List< Date >> (List< Date > consist of two values: StarDate and EndDate)`. For example I have an object `Profit__c` with field `GrossProfit__c` (currency) and User. I need summarize `GrossProfit__c` for each User in period `StarDate` and `EndDate` (createdDate between StarDate and EndDate). How can I get in result UserId and sum `GrossProfit__c` for each Range Of Dates.

Map:

```
 1. User1         {firstDate, secondDate}{firstDate2, secondDate2}
 2. User2         {firstDate3, secondDate3}{firstDate4, secondDate4}
```

So I need get:

```
1. User1 summ(grossProfit__c) between {firstDate,  secondDate}
 2. User1 summ(grossProfit__c) between {firstDate2,  secondDate2}
 3. User2 summ(grossProfit__c) between {firstDate3,  secondDate3}
 4. User2 summ(grossProfit__c) between {firstDate4,  secondDate4}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) for this.

```
[Select sum(grossProfit__c) from Profit__c Wher Day_Only(createdDate) >=: startDate and Day_Only(createdDate) <=: endDate group by userId];
```

Your query will look something like this.